# C# .NET 4.0 application won't run

Tags: c#, .net

I have a console application with the Target CPU set to `Any CPU` and Target Framework set to `.NET Framework 4 Client Profile`.

It runs fine on my Windows 7 PC. However when I run it on my Windows Server 2003 System I get the following error. I have .NET 4.0 installed on here.

[image: The Error]

What am I doing wrong here?

Here's the contents of my `App.config` file;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 

    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client"/></startup>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="chrome" value="20"/>
        <add key="OUTLOOK" value="230"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It looks like it's specifically asking for .NET 4.5, just in a wonky format.

Comment: I have not installed 4.5 on the Windows 2003 machine. It's a production box and I can't make any changes. But it defiantly has .NET 4.0 installed

Comment: Does your application have any external references that are built using .NET 4.5?

Comment: Yeah.  Install it up!  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653

Comment: .NET 4.5 is not supported on Windows 2003

Comment: It looks like a trojan messagebox. dotnet 4.5 won't install on server 2003 btw, but that's just a remark.

Comment: I think it's safe to say we can move on from the discussion about getting 4.5 installed and its incompatibility with Windows Server 2003 as the poster has already stated that it's a production box and he can't make changes to it.  Cheers.

Comment: Please post the manifest of your application.

Comment: What you have is not a .NET 4.0 application, it needs 4.5.  The question is *why?*

Comment: Manifest = AssemblyInfo.cs ?

Comment: Check your app.config if you have one. See this link http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx

Comment: Added to the question section

Comment: The manifest is a Win32 resource that gets embedded into the executable.  csc will create one if you haven't specified your own.

Comment: you can see the manifest contents in your output assembly with ILDASM.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309387(v=vs.71).aspx .  It isn't always easy to look at, but there will be human-readable names of most top-level dependencies.  It is also useful to look at your project references directly in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your app has a dependency on .NET 4.5.  You might have a reference to something that is built in 4.5 or one of the projects (maybe a class library?) could be built in .NET 4.5.

It may run fine on your Windows 7 machine because .NET 4.5 is an "in place" (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx) replacement for .NET 4.0.

Some others have suggested that Windows Server 2003 doesn't support .NET 4.5, while I can't confirm or deny that, if you can't install .NET 4.5 due to it being a production server, you'll need to eliminate the dependency to .NET 4.5 from your application.

Comment: Thank you. I was getting properties of a Process. I have long usedMemAmount = p.WorkingSet64; replacing it with long usedMemAmount = p.WorkingSet; fixed my problem :D

Answer (score -2):

.NET 4.5 is not supported on Windows Server 2003 per download link

[.NET 4.5 requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653)

Comment: But that was not the question.